# c# server and android client,connectivity

Tags: connectivity

i am trying to develop an application in c# which acts as a server for an android phone.i am using 32feet.net for bluetooth in c# and i have a server running in android, which simply sends a socket to server. the server running in pc need to listen the connection and display ,the status of connection. all these things are base for my project. the server code is as shown :

```
namespace testserver
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] dev;
        BluetoothDeviceInfo td=null;
        Guid id = new Guid("{00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff}");
      //  Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
       // Console.Read();
        dev = bc.DiscoverDevices();
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in dev)
        {
            if (d.DeviceName == "ST21i")//my phone name
            {
                td=d;
                break;
            }
        }
        try
        {

            BluetoothAddress addr = td.DeviceAddress;
            BluetoothListener bl = new BluetoothListener(addr, id);
            bl.Start();
            if (bl.AcceptSocket() != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception : "+e.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }


    }
}
```

}

and here is my android code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 BluetoothAdapter adapter;
     BluetoothDevice bd;
BluetoothSocket sock;
OutputStream ostr;
int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT;
String str="5C:AC:4C:DD:CC:0D";

private static final UUID id=UUID.fromString("00112233-4455-6677-8899-         aabbccddeeff");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

   if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked button",            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try
    { 
        bd=adapter.getRemoteDevice(str);                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server is    running at   "+bd.getName().toString()+"...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   sock=bd.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(id);                    sock.connect();
                ostr=sock.getOutputStream();
                ostr.write(0);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

my problems are :

1) in pc i am getting an exception, the requested address is not valid in its context(so that server cant run )
2)in phone, the service discovery failed( because of unavailability of server)

how can i correct the server and run the program ?

Answer (score 1):

i changed the bluetooth listener object's creation from 
`BluetoothListener bl = new BluetoothListener(addr, id);` to 
`BluetoothListener bl = new BluetoothListener(id);` and everything worked fine..